# Using CPLEX via SAGE when it's package installed

Tags: sage

I would like to use CPLEX via SAGE. 
There is this tutorial [here](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/thematic_tutorials/linear_programming.html#using-cplex-or-gurobi-through-sage).

However, my Sage is installed via a package (debian). Therefore, in my SAGE_ROOT (/usr/share/sagemath), I don't have local directory. 
Is there another directory then?

Comment: Is there any directory structure in `SAGE_ROOT` at all?

Comment: bin                    cremona    graphs
combinatorial_designs  ellcurves  installed
conway_polynomials     ext        reflexive_polytopes

Comment: Interesting.  You  may wish to ask this question at ask.sagemath.org, or perhaps https://alioth-lists.debian.net/cgi-bin/mailman/listinfo/debian-science-sagemath since the Debian Sage packagers  are pretty active right now.